# google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.6 is not picking current location and it’s not changing the map type also

Tags: flutter, location, picker, google-maps-flutter

MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) {
return MapLocationPicker(
// liteModeEnabled: true,

```
                    compassEnabled: true,
                    mapType: MapType.terrain,
                    apiKey: "AIzaSyD09LtDBfDoKPUn468fSUrBlSBrdDLDtIc",
                    canPopOnNextButtonTaped: true,
                    currentLatLng: const LatLng(29.121599, 76.396698),
                    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
                    onNext: (GeocodingResult? result) {
                      if (result != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          // result.geometry.location.
                          _locationController.text = result.formattedAddress ?? "";
                          _location = result.formattedAddress ?? "";
                          _lat = result.geometry.location.lat.toString();
                          _long = result.geometry.location.lng.toString();
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    onSuggestionSelected: (PlacesDetailsResponse? result) {
                      if (result != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          autocompletePlace =
                              result.result.formattedAddress ?? "";
                          _locationController.text = result.result.formattedAddress ?? "";
                          _location = result.result.formattedAddress ?? "";
                          _lat = result.result.geometry!.location.lat.toString();
                          _long = result.result.geometry!.location.lng.toString();
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
```

This is my code , I am stuck here , please help

I am trying to pick the current location and change map type , but it’s not working , I also could not find a way to customise these button show I can handle on click action on this.I am running this on iOS Simulator